# I keep on getting the error "Authentication Required" using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I keep on getting the "Authentication Required" error thrown when i run the following code:

```
import tweepy
import time


credentials = [
    {
        "consumer_key": 'xxx',
        "consumer_secret": 'xxx',
        "access_token": 'xxx',
        "access_token_secret": 'xxx'
    },
    {
        "consumer_key": 'xxx',
        "consumer_secret": 'xxx',
        "access_token": 'xxx',
        "access_token_secret": 'xxx'
    },
    {
        "consumer_key": 'xxx',
        "consumer_secret": 'xxx',
        "access_token": 'xxx',
        "access_token_secret": 'xxx'
    }
]


numofAccs = 3

username = "xxx"


apis = [tweepy.API(tweepy.OAuthHandler(c["consumer_key"], c["consumer_secret"]).set_access_token(c["access_token"], c["access_token_secret"])) for c in credentials]


latest_retweet_ids = [None] * numofAccs

while True:
    try:
        # Get the latest tweet from the specified user
        latest_tweet = apis[0].user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=1)[0]
        
        # If this is a new tweet, retweet it from each account and update the latest_retweet_id variables
        if latest_tweet.id not in latest_retweet_ids:
            for api in apis:
                time.sleep(10) #Delay for 10s on purpose
                api.retweet(latest_tweet.id)

                time.sleep(10) #Delay for 10s on purpose
                api.create_favorite(latest_tweet.id)

            latest_retweet_ids = [latest_tweet.id] * numofAccs
            
            print(f"Retweeted: {latest_tweet.text} from all " + numofAccs + " accounts.")
        else:
            print("No new tweets to retweet.")
        
    except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
        print(e)
        
    time.sleep(60) # Wait for 1 minute before checking again (Don't want to spam)
```

Is it something to do with the single or double quotation marks? I tried both and neither work. Is it maybe with the way i setup my dictionary? Any details would be great